# How to force a component to reload, on state change with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am coming from a React background (as far as my frontend skills are concerned) and need to do some work with Angular 7.

I want to change a variable in the class that declares the component(mycomponent.component.ts) and then to see the result in the browser, given the new values (which control, the elements that will be visible).

In React you would do that, by altering (in an immutable way) the `this.state` variable. I am trying to do this using the @Output directive as:

```
@Output() private hasResults: boolean = false;
//...

@Output()
buttonClick() {
    const result: Observable<Object> = this.myservice.queryData();
    result.subscribe(item => {

      if (item !== undefined) {
        this.hasResults = true;
      } else {
        this.hasResults = true;
      }
      console.log('item is ', item)
    })

  }
```

The service is doing a plain GET request.

Some elements in the respective html file depend on the value of hasResults to be printed and they are not reacting to the change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with scope, `hasResults` is marked as private which means the component's template does not have access to it. Remove the `private` access modifier and also you do not need `@Output` as that is used to broadcast events to subscribers.

```
hasResults: boolean = false;
//...

buttonClick() {
  const result: Observable<Object> = this.myservice.queryData();
  result.subscribe(item => {
    this.hasResults = item !== undefined;
    console.log('item is ', item)
  })
}
```